# how to get the original size of the image in java

Tags: java, image, size

I have tried to get the size of the image by `.length` in java.

However the original size of the image is several bytes higher than that.

What is the reason for this? Is there any code to get the original size?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        String imageFile1 = "C:/Users/Desktop/4.jpg";

        File file = new File(imageFile1);
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("The length in bytes " + imageInByte.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Show your effort. It's hard to help you if nobody but you can see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's about jpeg file header size.

If you want to get an original size when copying image file.
You can use just file copy rather then image file copy.

Or, you can make your own jpeg library, if you really want.

For just one example, 
this is one of the old-style code by using java's NIO.

```
private static void fileCopy(String from, String to) {
    FileChannel fromCh = null;
    FileChannel toCh = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(new File(from));
        fromCh = fin.getChannel();
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(to));
        toCh = fout.getChannel();

        fromCh.transferTo(0, fin.available(), toCh);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fin != null)
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        if (fout != null)
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

    }
}
```

You can get a file from the original file with the same size.

[image]

Check the reference site below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

I tested it the difference between two file, one is the original another is the copy one. I got an jpeg image from googling.

I modified some code form [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/GetJpegProperties.htm) in order to analyze the jpeg header file .
Here is the method:

```
final public static ImageProperties getJpegProperties(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        // check for "magic" header
        byte[] buf = new byte[2];
        int count = in.read(buf, 0, 2);
        if (count < 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
        }
        if ((buf[0]) != (byte) 0xFF || (buf[1]) != (byte) 0xD8) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
        }

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        char[] comment = null;

        boolean hasDims = false;
        boolean hasComment = false;
        int ch = 0;
        int totalHeaderLen = 0;

        while (ch != 0xDA && !(hasDims && hasComment)) {
            /* Find next marker (JPEG markers begin with 0xFF) */
            while (ch != 0xFF) {
                ch = in.read();
            }
            /* JPEG markers can be padded with unlimited 0xFF's */
            while (ch == 0xFF) {
                ch = in.read();
            }
            /* Now, ch contains the value of the marker. */

            int length = 256 * in.read();
            length += in.read();

            totalHeaderLen += length;

            if (length < 2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
            }
            /* Now, length contains the length of the marker. */

            if (ch >= 0xC0 && ch <= 0xC3) {
                in.read();
                height = 256 * in.read();
                height += in.read();
                width = 256 * in.read();
                width += in.read();
                for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2 - 5; foo++) {
                    in.read();
                }
                hasDims = true;
            } else if (ch == 0xFE) {
                // that's the comment marker
                comment = new char[length - 2];
                for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++)
                    comment[foo] = (char) in.read();
                hasComment = true;
            } else {
                // just skip marker
                for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++) {
                    in.read();
                }
            }
        }

        if(comment == null) comment = "no comment".toCharArray();

        return (new ImageProperties(width, height, new String(comment), totalHeaderLen, "jpeg"));

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main method is :

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
    String imageFile1 = "resource/4.jpg";
    String imageFile2 = "resource/4_jpg.jpg";

    //copyImage(imageFile1);

    ImageProperties origin = getJpegProperties(new File(imageFile1));
    ImageProperties copyed = getJpegProperties(new File(imageFile2));

    System.out.println("============ Original one ===========");
    System.out.println("comments(origin) : " + origin.getComments());
    System.out.println("Height(origin) : " + origin.getHeight());
    System.out.println("Width(origin) : " + origin.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Header Length(origin) : " + origin.getHeaderLen());
    //System.out.println("suffix(origin) : " + origin.getSuffix());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("============ Copy one ===========");
    System.out.println("comments(copy) : " + copyed.getComments());
    System.out.println("Height(copy) : " + copyed.getHeight());
    System.out.println("Width(copy) : " + copyed.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Header Length(copy) : " + copyed.getHeaderLen());
    //System.out.println("suffix(copy) : " + copyed.getSuffix());

}
```

I copy the original image first using copyImage method here.

```
static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage source) {
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getType());
    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return b;
}
```

I can see the difference of the two images in the explorer.

[image]

I got a different header size when running the program.

The output:

```
============ Original one ===========
comments(origin) : no comment
Height(origin) : 534
Width(origin) : 800
Header Length(origin) : 21269

============ Copy one ===========
comments(copy) : no comment
Height(copy) : 534
Width(copy) : 800
Header Length(copy) : 603
```

Header Length is different as you can see the result.

Here is full test code.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;


public class Misc {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        String imageFile1 = "resource/4.jpg";
        String imageFile2 = "resource/4_jpg.jpg";
        String imageFile3 = "resource/4_org.jpg";

        fileCopy(imageFile1, imageFile3);
        //copyImage(imageFile1);

        ImageProperties origin = getJpegProperties(new File(imageFile1));
        ImageProperties copyed = getJpegProperties(new File(imageFile2));

        System.out.println("============ Original one ===========");
        System.out.println("comments(origin) : " + origin.getComments());
        System.out.println("Height(origin) : " + origin.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width(origin) : " + origin.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Header Length(origin) : " + origin.getHeaderLen());
        //System.out.println("suffix(origin) : " + origin.getSuffix());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("============ Copy one ===========");
        System.out.println("comments(copy) : " + copyed.getComments());
        System.out.println("Height(copy) : " + copyed.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width(copy) : " + copyed.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Header Length(copy) : " + copyed.getHeaderLen());
        //System.out.println("suffix(copy) : " + copyed.getSuffix());

    }

    static class ImageProperties {
        private final int width;
        private final int height;
        private final String comments;
        private final int headerLen;
        private final String suffix;

        public ImageProperties(
            final int width, final int height, final String comments, final int headerLen,
            final String suffix) 
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.comments = comments;
            this.suffix = suffix;
            this.headerLen = headerLen;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public String getComments() {
            return comments;
        }

        public String getSuffix() {
            return suffix;
        }

        public int getHeaderLen() {
            return headerLen;
        }

    }

    final public static ImageProperties getJpegProperties(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

            // check for "magic" header
            byte[] buf = new byte[2];
            int count = in.read(buf, 0, 2);
            if (count < 2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
            }
            if ((buf[0]) != (byte) 0xFF || (buf[1]) != (byte) 0xD8) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
            }

            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            char[] comment = null;

            boolean hasDims = false;
            boolean hasComment = false;
            int ch = 0;
            int totalHeaderLen = 0;

            while (ch != 0xDA && !(hasDims && hasComment)) {
                /* Find next marker (JPEG markers begin with 0xFF) */
                while (ch != 0xFF) {
                    ch = in.read();
                }
                /* JPEG markers can be padded with unlimited 0xFF's */
                while (ch == 0xFF) {
                    ch = in.read();
                }
                /* Now, ch contains the value of the marker. */

                int length = 256 * in.read();
                length += in.read();

                totalHeaderLen += length;

                if (length < 2) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid Jpeg file!");
                }
                /* Now, length contains the length of the marker. */

                if (ch >= 0xC0 && ch <= 0xC3) {
                    in.read();
                    height = 256 * in.read();
                    height += in.read();
                    width = 256 * in.read();
                    width += in.read();
                    for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2 - 5; foo++) {
                        in.read();
                    }
                    hasDims = true;
                } else if (ch == 0xFE) {
                    // that's the comment marker
                    comment = new char[length - 2];
                    for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++)
                        comment[foo] = (char) in.read();
                    hasComment = true;
                } else {
                    // just skip marker
                    for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++) {
                        in.read();
                    }
                }
            }

            if(comment == null) comment = "no comment".toCharArray();

            return (new ImageProperties(width, height, new String(comment), totalHeaderLen, "jpeg"));

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage source) {
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getType());
        Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return b;
    }


    private static void fileCopy(String from, String to) {
        FileChannel fromCh = null;
        FileChannel toCh = null;
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(new File(from));
            fromCh = fin.getChannel();
            fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(to));
            toCh = fout.getChannel();

            fromCh.transferTo(0, fin.available(), toCh);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fin != null)
                try {
                    fin.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            if (fout != null)
                try {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

        }
    }

}
```

So, I think the extra information of the jpeg image skipped by the image io library in java.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It really helped.